# I got the following question in my calculus 1 exam and i wanna know the right answer

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is the lim of the sequence $(e^1 -1 ) + (e^{1/2}  -1 ) + \dots + (e^{1/n} -1)$ as n approaches infinity ? Personally i got the answer $e-1$

Comment: Can you please add your approach? It would be very helpful.

Comment: I did notice that this can be done using geomtric sequence sum as (a1(1-q^n))/1-q

Comment: How would i approach it other than using the geometric sum ,

Comment: As the linked duplicate explains, use the definition of $e$ and compare your sum to the harmonic sum.

Comment: Its not clear what the final lim is

Comment: You said that you got the answer $e-1$, but note that the very first term is $e-1$, and the following terms are all positive.

Comment: How is it not clear what the final limit is? The linked thread says it repeatedly. Do you not know what "diverges" means? I will have to say that this series seems a bit much to ask of a Calc I class, at least without copious hints.